# Drupal 7- How can alter the data when downloading views records (Data Export)?

Tags: 7, views, hooks

Any suggestions/solutions/hook for altering the data when downloading view records (Data Export)?

Comment: What kind of alteration do you need to do? Have you tried any of the normal views hooks? We need a lot more info on what you're doing/trying to do.